# React state does not get updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I know there's been many questions with this topic asked already, but it really feels like each and every one of them is different and I cannot find one that matches my issue closely enough.

I have a grid with draggable `ItemComponent`s. Once selected, additional action icons show up (`ItemActionIcon`). I would very much like to unselect the component (and effectively hide the action icons) once one of the actions is clicked.

[image]

and so in line 77 `<div onClick={() => this.setState({selected: false})} key={index}>` I'm attempting to update the state of `selected` to false. It already works just fine in all other cases mentioned in the file. But not in this case. When I click the icon, I can see with a debugger (or with a console.log when I tried it) that the `onClick` action is triggered as expected and the `ItemComponent` even gets another call to the `render` method, but the `this.state.selected` is still set to `true`.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Draggable, {DraggableBounds} from "react-draggable";
import ItemComponentAction from "./ItemComponentAction";
import ItemActionIcon from "./ItemActionIcon";

export interface Position {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

export interface ItemComponentProps {
    gridSquareSize: number;
    canvasBounds: DraggableBounds;
    margin: number;
    position: Position;
}

interface ItemComponentState {
    gridSquareSize: number;
    canvasBounds: DraggableBounds;
    margin: number;
    selected: boolean;
}

export default abstract class ItemComponent extends Component<ItemComponentProps> {

    protected abstract readonly icon: string;
    protected abstract readonly actions: ItemComponentAction[];

    state: ItemComponentState;

    protected constructor(props: ItemComponentProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            gridSquareSize: props.gridSquareSize,
            canvasBounds: props.canvasBounds,
            margin: props.margin,
            selected: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Draggable grid={[this.state.gridSquareSize / 2, this.state.gridSquareSize / 2]}
                       defaultPosition={{
                           x: this.state.margin + this.props.position.x * this.state.gridSquareSize,
                           y: this.state.margin + this.props.position.y * this.state.gridSquareSize
                       }}
                       handle=".handle"
                       bounds={this.state.canvasBounds}
                       onDrag={() => this.setState({selected: false})}
            >
                <div tabIndex={0}
                     className="handle"
                     onClick={() => this.setState({selected: true})}
                     onBlur={() => this.setState({selected: false})}
                     style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        backgroundColor: 'red',
                        width: this.state.gridSquareSize,
                        height: this.state.gridSquareSize,
                        cursor: "move"
                     }}
                >
                    {this.icon}

                    {
                        !this.state.selected || !this.actions.length
                           ? null
                           : (
                                <div style={{
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                    bottom: "0"
                                }}>
                                    {
                                        this.actions.map((action, index) => (
                                            <div onClick={() => this.setState({selected: false})} key={index}>
                                                <ItemActionIcon {...action}/>
                                            </div>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </div>
                            )
                    }
                </div>
            </Draggable>
        );
    }
}
```

so what's the deal?

Comment: Seems like you have an onclick handler in the parent div that sets `selected` to `false`? If you click the inner div, won't the outer div onclick function also run...?

Comment: nope... it actually was not it... the parent's onClick does not get triggered...
but I'll extract the whole thing anyway. Perhaps this will trigger this thing

Comment: What did you do to verify whether or not the parent onClick was triggered?

Comment: i wasn't sure if I could trust the debugger (the breakpoints often end up in wrong places after you compile TS), so I simply added the console.log()

Comment: It's likely that the onClick actually is being triggered and you just aren't seeing it or logging it visibly. To further verify this, you could try leaving the code the same as your example in the question, and doing `event.stopPropagation()` on the inner div onClick event.

Comment: that did it. I cannot trust any debuggers... thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an answer with the details so we can mark your question as resolved. Please mark the answer as "accepted". :)

Answer (score 1):

The outer `<div>` of your component has its own `onClick` handler which is setting the value of your state back to `false`. Try using `stopPropagation()` on the inner `onClick` handled event. That will prevent the event from propagating to the outer parent `<div>`, and only the inner `onClick` handler will execute when it is clicked on.

```
{
  !this.state.selected || !this.actions.length ? null : (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: "0"
      }}
    >
      {this.actions.map((action, index) => (
        <div
          onClick={e => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.setState({ selected: false });
          }}
          key={index}
        >
          <ItemActionIcon {...action} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```